# How to programatically minimize a Notification on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

Android supports minimizing notification so that they only take one line at the bottom. This particularly useful for "sticky" notification which are fronting foreground services. I noticed that some applications pop their notification already Minimized such as Google map and that other Like Samsung Health allow you to minimize it by holding the notification.

Is there a way to minimize the notification programmatically (like what Google Maps is doing)? Or is Google cheating somehow and other applications have to let the user minimize it?